# Changing the location of the components folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, dependency-management

In Visual Studio 2012, I am using a Xamarin.iOS project type and when I add components to a project, they're added to the folder: [Solution-directory]/Components/[component-name]/

Is it possible to choose where the components are stored?

My dependency management strategy is to store the dependencies outside of the project and solution area in their own folder.

I guess I could rip out the DLL from the /lib/ folder within the component directory, but I am wondering if there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the components directory with a `components.config` file. This is [detailed here regarding Xamarin Studio](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/components_walkthrough/#Configuring_the_Components_Directory), but I just tested this myself by having it in the root of the solution directory, and it did work.